# Use 2.0 web reference with .net 4.0 project in visual studio 2010

Tags: .net, web-services

I want to do the following, and any help would be appreciated:

Create a library that uses .net 2.0 runtime to create .net 2.0 web references.

Create a windows forms project that uses .net 4.0. This project will reference and use the web services generated from the 2.0 class library.

I am running into the following issue when compiling the .net 4.0 project:

'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

The assembly that this error is giving is located in the class library, how can I tell Visual Studio to find it in that library?

Comment: Have you added a reference to the system.web.services?

Comment: Have you installed the AJAX.net 1.1 web extensions?

Comment: In the windows forms project I can't reference that specific assembly because its not available to .net 4.0. I have no idea what ajax.net web extensions will solve?

Comment: @user: why do you want to do this? Why not simply use a service reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not located in that class library at all. It is *referenced* by the library. If you want to use 2.0 web services you need reference that assembly in your client library.

Comment: so how exactly do I use 2.0 web technology in a .net 4.0 windows forms project?

Comment: I should add that you can't add a reference to that assembly in the windows forms project because then it would have to target 2.0 framework.